# Div with large pixel height not working in firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, height

I have tried to set large pixel value to the height of a div element in the html page. The pixel value gets exponential form and it doesn't work in firefox and IE browsers. but its working only in chrome browser.

**HTML**

```
<div style="height:23423432px;">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{    
  background: green;
}
```

Can I set large pixel height to the div? Is there any limitation for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This would be entirely browser dependent and, in practical terms...what's the point?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637530/whats-the-maximum-pixel-value-of-css-width-and-height-properties