# What's the min/max of vh units?

Tags: css

Like, what are the browser limitations? If I have 99999999999999vh will it actually be 99999999999999vh or will it be something weird like 2145629vh?

Comment: It's [a percentage of the viewport size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths). I guess that you could theoretically have an element size that is many (thousand?) times the height or width of the viewport, without limit, but I don't know what the practical purpose of this would be. I think it's a question about how a browser would handle really big elements rather than a limitation of the unit itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the viewport height (vh) [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths), it does not mention there is a limit of min/max value. However, in [Section 5 of CSS Values and Units: Numeric Data Types](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#numeric-types), it mentions that:

> CSS theoretically supports infinite precision and infinite ranges for all value types; however in reality implementations have finite capacity. UAs should support reasonably useful ranges and precisions.

and some [SO users do test the limit of values of each browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16637689/188331), and the results are as follow:

```
Firefox: 33554400px
Chrome:  33554428px
Opera:   33554428px
IE 9:    21474836.47px
```

and the above behavior is explained in [Section 5: Distance Units](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths):

> While some properties allow negative length values, this may complicate the formatting and there may be implementation-specific limits. If a negative length value is allowed but cannot be supported, it must be converted to the nearest value that can be supported.

Hope the above can answer your question.

Comment: I wish I could vote this up twice. Well researched answer! :)

Comment: I find it odd how the maximum difference between Chrome and Firefox is 28px. I wonder how they decided on that seemingly arbitrary value. Great answer.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Don't FF & Chrome have differing versions of what consititues 100vw...one includes the scrollbar and the other doesn't? Could that be it? I would assume that they merely set the max vh to the same as the vw max pixel value.