# Maximum value for tag width in html

Tags: html, css, canvas

what is upper limit for width in html tag ...

i am using canvas where i need to have maximum width for parent to render content dynamically

```
.layout{
 width: 10000;//is it a valid value for width 
}
```

**Is there any upper limit for width value**

Comment: have you tried `width: 100%;` ?

Comment: I don't think it's valid, you need to specify a unit measure like `px` or `percent`. I think the better solution might be to simply set `width: 100%`

Comment: You have a complete answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16637689/4607733). Please check before asking a question.

Comment: yups with 100% canvas does show fully

Comment: Note that canvas drawing area has its own limitations : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element

Comment: A very large canvas (a very large element of any kind) will slow your app. If you're testing the maximum size of a canvas element then the question you should be asking is how to refactor your code to use a reasonably sized canvas. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on browser. Just give it a very big value and then inspect in dev-tools. My chrome gives 37282700 pixels for an element with style="width: 999999999999999999999px;"

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your CSS

```
tagName{
    width: 100%;
}
```

this property always set your width of selected tag to maximum-width, works on all screen sizes