# element.scrollTop has different behavior across browsers while setting a very large value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to **scroll to bottom without triggering layout/reflow**.

So I tried to set a fixed large number(`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` or 1000000000000000) to scrollTop, which caused different behavior across browsers:

- Firefox(59.02)/Safari(11.1): scroll to top
- Chrome(66.0.3359.139): scroll to bottom

Here's the [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/4vuaf8fd/1/).

Is this a bug or there's something I went wrong...?

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can try with scrollTop to the calculated height of the page.
It is simpler and straight forward.
Steps to follow
1. Find the height of the document / any container div

> var containerHeight= $("#box").height();

2. scrollTop with containerHeight.

> document.querySelector('#box').scrollTop =  containerHeight;

This will surely work with any behaviour mismatch.

Comment: In my case, I don't want to access height in loop because my DOMs are dirty each loop. And that will trigger a reflow/layout everytime. So I tried to give it a fixed number.

Comment: Giving a fixed number is not a right idea / solution, particularly if it is responsive.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the different max values for elements across browsers. For instance, in Chrome the limit is 33554428px. A complete list was given here: [What's the maximum pixel value of CSS width and height properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637530/whats-the-maximum-pixel-value-of-css-width-and-height-properties)